# Start learning French through English

Tags: ressources, apprentissage

I desire to learn French, but I am very new to it, i.e. I don't know even a single word in French.

I googled this, but I could not access a proper site to learn French online.

**How can I learn French online, or what are simple & elegant books for beginners ?**

Comment: The language-learning offer online and offline, free or paying is rather large, especially for commonly used languages as French, I don't think you'll find here an answer more relevant than a google search. Depending on your location you might also find French-speaking groups for beginners and stuff like that... being french-speaking I must admit I couldn't give advise on which site/software/app to use, but there's certainly a lot of it !

Comment: @Nikana Reklawyks thank you for edit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](/tour), not a link collection. I'm afraid that questions asking for list of resources do very poorly in our system: they tend to accumulate random lists of vaguely-related dubiously-applicable links, and this one is shaping up to be no exception. See also http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/127 and http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/575 on our meta site.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with this application to get some basic words/expressions https://www.busuu.com

There is an android app of it so it can be with you everywhere!

Bon courage ;)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what other people think about [TV5's material](http://apprendre.tv5monde.com/en) ?

Otherwise, there really is an enormous amount of written material out there. French has always been the number one language learnt by the English-speaking world (the British certainly), so I would have a look in a bookshop. Personally I prefer to start learning a language with a proper book, that you can take on the train, to a café etc.

Comment: Could you please suggest any particular book?

Comment: Igot 403 for the link you specific

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend for you to start learning French like I started to learn English : from French TV shows. Shows like Braquo, Hard, Un village français, les revenants are realy worth watching and will improve your French in no time.